# Sybase Connection with Flask sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sybase, sqlalchemy-sybase

Im trying to connect Sybase database with flask SQLalchemy using a ODBC connection .

My connection string :
'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' = "sybase+pyodbc://username:passw@rd@host:port/dbname?driver=Adaptive+Server+Enterprise"

[Getting this Error :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9WEY.png)

But I'm pretty sure i'm using the right port in the connection string. But when i try connect to connect to the same instance using this method .

Second method :

```
con = pyodbc.connect(server=server ,port=port ,username=username ,password=password ,driver=driver)
```

The connection works perfectly fine now with the same connection details.

Can anyone help me in building the connection string URL and help me fix this. Cause I want to use the "db Object" instead of "cursor Object ".

Answer (score 1):

After so much research I found that, this error is due incorrect parameter in the connection string.

**Invalid port number error** will be also fixed with this block of code .

Code here :

```
import urllib
connection_string = (
    'DRIVER=Adaptive Server Enterprise;'
    'SERVER=server;'
    'PORT=port;'
    'UID=username;PWD=password;'
    'DATABASE=dbname;'
)
connection_uri = f"sybase+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = connection_uri # connection string for SQLALchemy
```

This code is best solution .

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [Getting Connected](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-sybase/wiki/Getting-Connected) wiki page, "Hostname Connections" are not supported. You can either create an ODBC DSN, or use your pyodbc connection string with an ODBC direct pass-through connection:

```py
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connection_string = (
    'DRIVER=SAP ASE ODBC driver;'
    'SERVER=centos7-vm01;'
    'PORT=5000;'
    'UID=scott;PWD=tiger;'
    'DATABASE=mydatabase;'
    'charset=utf8;'
)
connection_uri = f"sybase+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"
engine = create_engine(connection_uri)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick response. I have a found the right fit for me . Post it here . Cheers !!